# How to resolve from autofac parent scope without passing it around multiple times?

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

I have an application that creates a lifetime scope at some point like so:

```
    public class Main
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            using (ILifetimeScope scope = AutofacContainer.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                scope.Resolve<SomeClass>();
            }
        }
    }
```

Within `SomeClass` I have logic which then calls a lot of different classes and so on.. 
Then, about 10 methods down the call stack I need to use the main scope to do this:

```
public class ActivatorFactory : IActivatorFactory
{
    public T Create<T>(Type instance)
    {
        using (ILifetimeScope scope = AutofacContainer.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            return (T)scope.Resolve(instance);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with that is that now I've created a new scope which is just used to resolve a runtime type. I want to be able to use the main scope to resolve this type. How can I do so without passing the main scope down to this factory class through 10 different methods/functions?
The only "hacky" solution I thought of is to just have a static property on my `ActivatorFactory` and set the scope in my `Main` class like so:

```
    public class Main
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            using (ILifetimeScope scope = AutofacContainer.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                ActivatorFactory.Scope = scope;
                scope.Resolve<SomeClass>();
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a cleaner solution to use the main scope in another part of my application?

Comment: It seems to me that `ActivatorFactory` shouldn't really exist if you're using an Autofac container. Why do you need ActivatorFactory -- what does it do that Autofac cannot do for you in a much nicer way?

Autofac is able to inject factories for you already, please see documentation here: http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html

Specfically the "Dynamic Instantiation" and "Parameterized Instantiation" sections

Comment: @ivanPfeff I'm mainly using the ActivatorFactory for unit tests. With NSubstitute I'm able to test if a type is instantiated or not.

Answer (score 3):

I had this need for a `CancellationTokenSource` instance per lifetime scope, where children are linked to their parent. If the the `root` scope's `CancellationTokenSource`, is canceled, all children lifetime scope's `CancellationToken` are canceled. To accomplish this, I created:

```
private sealed class ParentLifetimeScopeAccessor
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _lifetimeScope;

    public ParentLifetimeScopeAccessor(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
    {
        _lifetimeScope = lifetimeScope;
        _lifetimeScope.ChildLifetimeScopeBeginning += OnChildLifetimeScopeBeginning;
    }

    public ILifetimeScope ParentLifetimeScope { get; private set; }

    private void OnChildLifetimeScopeBeginning(object sender, LifetimeScopeBeginningEventArgs e) =>
        e.LifetimeScope.Resolve<ParentLifetimeScopeAccessor>().ParentLifetimeScope = _lifetimeScope;
}
```

With a registration, you can now access your parent's scope:

```
builder.RegisterType<ParentLifetimeScopeAccessor>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

With the parent lifetime scope accessor, linked `CancellationTokenSource` instances can be created:

```
private static CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSourceFactory(IComponentContext context)
{
    var scopeAccessor = context.Resolve<ParentLifetimeScopeAccessor>();
    var parentScope = scopeAccessor.ParentLifetimeScope;
    return null == parentScope
        ? new CancellationTokenSource()
        : CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(parentScope.Resolve<CancellationTokenSource>().Token);
}
```

`CancellationToken` resolver:

```
private static CancellationToken CancellationTokenResolver(IComponentContext context) =>
context.Resolve<CancellationTokenSource>().Token;
```

Two registrations:

```
builder.Register(CancellationTokenSourceFactory).AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.Register(CancellationTokenResolver).AsSelf().InstancePerDependency();
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you're not using `ActivatorFactory` for your app** (and you shouldn't be if you're using inversion of control) then delete it and think about what you're trying to test.

- **Are you trying to test that you can generally just resolve things from Autofac?** Autofac has a raft of unit tests as well as millions of successful users. No value in testing the framework.
- **Are you trying to test that you registered all the things you needed to register?** There's not a lot of value in that, either, for a couple of reasons: first, you'll hit that at runtime pretty quickly and see it in those tests; second, in a large, decoupled system those tests get really stale really quickly. It's a maintenance hassle.
- **Are you trying to test that a specific object graph can be composed based on your registrations?** I might buy this one. See below.

Let's say it's the last thing - you have a really complex and troublesome object graph you want to ensure you can create because people keep breaking it. I could see that.

**Separate your registrations out into an Autofac module. Use the Autofac module to test.**

```
public class MyRegistrations : Autofac.Module
{
  protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
  {
    builder.RegisterType<Thing>();
    // and all your other registrations.
  }
}
```

then in the unit test

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule<MyRegistrations>();
var container = builder.Build();
var thing = container.Resolve<Thing>();
// Assert on the resolved thing.
```

You can use that same module to encapsulate your registrations in the app and then you'll actually be testing the complex registration but without a factory you're not using.

**Warning: It is a slippery slope between testing some complex registration and testing *all* registrations.** Like I said, you really don't want to test every registration you have. I've fallen down this slope. It's a maintenance nightmare. Add a registration to the module/app, add a test. Uh oh, we refactored, now the registrations are all different. Ugh. That's less testing about behavior than about characterization (not "what do I want it to do" but "what does it do now"). Pain. Suffering.

**If you *are* using `ActivatorFactory` in your app** for, say, service location instead of using some more standard thing like [CommonServiceLocator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommonServiceLocator/) that already does that for you and for which [Autofac already directly integrates](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Extras.CommonServiceLocator/)... then just test `ActivatorFactory` with a real container but with some arbitrary test registrations rather than the whole set from the real app. The functionality of `ActivatorFactory` doesn't have any bearing on what's *registered inside it*.

And, yeah, if you're using `ActivatorFactory` and need to keep it around, you'll have to hand it an `ILifetimeScope` at app startup. That's how service locators work. You'll see that all over in the [Autofac docs](http://autofac.readthedocs.io) when you look at how to integrate with apps like ASP.NET, WCF, and others.